# How to include a counter to Spring Batch JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: spring-batch

The following batch item writer is defined in my project and I want to add counter to  and a date to . How do you do that?

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
        .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
        .sql("INSERT INTO t(counter, firstname, lastname, loaddate) VALUES (<HOW TO ADD COUNTER HERE>, :firstName, :lastName, <HOW TO ADD A DATE>)")
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include counter and date fields in your bean and set the values for counter and date in ItemProcessor. Once you do that, the below would work.

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Employee> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Employee>()
        .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
        .sql("INSERT INTO t(counter, firstname, lastname, loaddate) VALUES (**:counter**, :firstName, :lastName, **:loadDate**)")
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .build();
}
```